# Render animation|still with a palette and dithering?

Tags: rendering

Is there any way to render frames with a reduced colour palette and optionally floyd steinberg dithering? Like setting an image to indexed in the GIMP.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67098/any-simple-way-to-apply-a-color-index-to-achieve-things-like-256-color-range-a

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't work with specific palettes or dithering but it's good.