# Pre-determined Color Palette in Render

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

Are there any existing methods to reduce a render to a specific set of predetermined / indexed colors within Blender (ideally with optional Floyd-Steinberg dithering) ?

I've been digging, I can't find anything that actually accomplishes or automates this without leaving the program. [This post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67098/any-simple-way-to-apply-a-color-index-to-achieve-things-like-256-color-range-a) has a similar question, but the answer doesn't allow for specific color choice as far as I understand. 
Gimp does an excellent job of restricting to specific colors but having to save a render, open in gimp, convert and then view is a bit tedious, especially for animations.
It should find the closest match for each color.
It should be visible in Blender (render window or viewport).
I assume it would require some scripting to be able to achieve this.

The result I'm trying to obtain is like so:  (Mind the image upload artifacts)
[image]

Comment: Is it for pixel art?

Comment: GIMP does not do an excellent job of restricting to specific colors. GIMP does not use [gamma-aware image dithering](https://www.nayuki.io/page/gamma-aware-image-dithering).